# How to remove Missing values when running Fisher's Exact test on all columns of a data frame

Tags: r, lapply

I have a data frame (df) consisting of a set of independent variables (V,W,X,...) as columns and each row is a different sample. The last row shows the dependent variable (AH).

```
R <- lapply (data, fisher.test, y=data$AH)
R
```

Of course, my actual data frame has more dependent variables (around 60). Also, I have some missing data in my variables. I have tried different arguments in the `lapply` function code such as  `na.rm = TRUE` and `!is.na`.

I have also tried `na.omit`. The code looks like:

```
R <- lapply (df, fisher.test, na.omit(df), y=df$AH)
```

But it gives the following error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...):cannot allocate memory block of size 134217728 Tb.

This is a subset of my data set (of course, just part of it):

```
    V  W  X  Y  Z AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH
1  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2
2   2  2  2  2 NA  2  2  1  2  2  2  2  2
3   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  2 NA NA  2  2
4   1  1  2 NA  2 NA  2  2  1  2  2  2  2
5   1  1  2  2  2 NA  2  1  2 NA  1 NA  2
6   2  2  1  2  2  1  2  2  2  2  2 NA  1
7   1  1  2  2  2  2  2  1  1  2  2  1  2
8   1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  2
9  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1
10  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  2  2  2  2  2  1
11 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  2  1
12  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  2  2  2  2  2
13  2 NA  2  2  2 NA  2 NA  1  2  2 NA  2
14 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1
15  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
16  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  1  2  1  2  2
17  1  1  1  2  2  1  2  1  1  2  1  1  2
18  1  1  2  2  2 NA  1  1 NA  2  1  2  2
19  2 NA  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1
20 NA NA  2  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  1
21  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
22  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1
23  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
24  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  2  2
25  2  2  2  2  2 NA  2  1  2  2  1  1  2
26  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
27  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
28 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 31 rows ]
```

How can I remove these NAs in my Fisher's Exact test?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a subset of your data that gives the problem? You probably have too many categories so you run into memory problems.

Comment: @ekstroem: This is just part of the dataset:

Comment: Yeah - but without seeing your actual data (or just an example) then it's hard to pinpoint exactly what is causing your problem

Comment: @ekstroem I had added part of the data set in the explanations. To be precise, I have 34 variables and 30 samples. And it is strange, because when I did the Fisher's Exact test, without excluding the NAs, it works. And of course, it does not give me a correct p-value because the missing values are included in the analysis.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't provided data that reproduces the error you mention in your post so it is difficult to know exactly what is wrong in your example.

The `fisher.test` function automatically disregards the missings you have in your data, and it does not produce incorrect p-values (and you do not mention an example where it is wrong and in what sense it is wrong). See here

```
> fisher.test(c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2))

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2) and c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
p-value = 0.02857
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.339059      Inf
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
       Inf
```

Same analysis with the first pair of observations removed yields the same result as when the missings are included.

```
> fisher.test(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2))

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2) and c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
p-value = 0.02857
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.339059      Inf
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
       Inf
```

However, you might have a problem with this line

```
lapply (df, fisher.test, na.omit(df), y=df$AH)
```

since `na.omit(df)` will be passed as the *third* argument to `fisher.test` which is workspace. It should be enough with your initial call although you may run into problems if you do not end up with 2 categories for each independent variable.